# Flask-SQLAlchemy - get distinct elements in QuerySelectField?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

So I am populating the queryselectfield from my database.

```
def place_query():
    
    return Place.query
    
class CreateItineraryForm(FlaskForm):

   opts = QuerySelectField('Select a city',query_factory=place_query,allow_blank=True,get_label='city',validators=[DataRequired()])

   days = IntegerField('Enter the number of days of stay',validators=[DataRequired()])

   submit = SubmitField("Generate Itinerary")
```

But since my database has multiple tuples with the same city. So in my select field the same city shows up multiple times. Is there a way I can select only distinct city names?

This is the schema if that's helpful -

```
class Place(db.Model):

__tablename__ = 'places'

id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)

name = db.Column(db.String(64),nullable=False,index=True)

lat = db.Column(db.Float,nullable=False)

long = db.Column(db.Float,nullable=False)

city = db.Column(db.String(30),nullable=False,index=True)

user_reviews = db.relationship('Review',backref='subject',lazy=True)

def __init__(self,name,lat,long,city):

self.name = name

self.lat = lat

self.long = long

self.city = city
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the trick was to not use `QuerySelectField` but to use `SelectField`.

This is the new code -

```
# this returns a tuple of the form (city_name,)
cities = db.session.query(Place.city).group_by(Place.city).order_by(Place.city).all()

city_list = []

# here we create a list from the tuple
def create_list(cities):
    for city in cities:
        city_list.append(city[0])

    return city_list
```

And the new select field looks like this -

```
opts = SelectField('Select a city',validators=[DataRequired()],choices=create_list(cities))
```

Comment: You can use [distinct](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.distinct) to get the same list of tuples:  `cities = db.session.query(Place.city.distinct()).all()`